# How to get the error line number of yaml validation using cerberus?

Tags: python, validation, yaml

I am using **[cerberus](https://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/)** for validating my yaml file against predefined schema as shown below

```
import yaml

schema_text = '''
name:
type: string
age:
type: integer
min: 10
'''

input_text = '''
name: Little Joe                     *(Line 1)*
age: 5                               *(Line 2)*
'''

schema_yaml = yaml.load(schema_text)
input_yaml = yaml.load(input_text)
v.validate(input_yaml , schema_yaml)

v.errors
**{'age': ['min value is 10']}**
```

When handling YAML validation errors, instead of just displaying the error message to the user, it would be super helpful to display the line number(s) of the validation error as well so the user can figure out what's going on.

- For example :

**{'age': ['min value is 10..error found at line number 2']}**

Is there such option available in cerberus ? Any leads would be much helpful.

Comment: To me this doesn't look like YAML validation. You use YAML to load your schema (with the outdated PyYAML parser). You are validating `document` (a python data structure) using the Python data structure loaded from YAML, and then expect the line number in the YAML file from which the schema is loaded, which IMO isn't very useful for finding the error in `document`

Comment: Hi @Anthon. I have placed a sample code base, actually in our project we will be giving the yaml document as input(input.yaml) which cerberus will validate with predefined yaml schema(schema.yaml) and returns errors if there is any violation in yaml data against the schema. But in addition to that error log I need the line number as well from the input.yaml, where this error is occuring from as shown below.For eg :                                                                                 "name": [
      "must be of string type", 
      "at line 5"
    ]

Comment: That makes more sense, before it looked like you wanted the line number from schema.yaml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple things you should be aware of. First of all your `schema_yaml` is invalid YAML as
all keys for a single mapping need to be **unique**. PyYAML will however happily load that overwriting
`string` with `integer`. You actually want to get an error message and detect you should
indent some of the lines in `schema_yaml`. You should also make it a habit to add a backslash after
the opening triple-quotes, otherwise your string starts with an empty line and your
counting of line numbers will be off by one.

Using `ruamel.yaml` (disclaimer: I am the author of that package) you can keep
track of the lines a key was assigned to during the creation of the mapping. The
start_mark of the key node has the line number (starting at 0):

```py
import sys
import cerberus
import ruamel.yaml

schema_text = '''\
name:
  type: string
age:
  type: integer
  min: 10
'''

input_text = '''\
name: Little Joe                  #   *(Line 1)*
age: 5                            #   *(Line 2)*
'''

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe') # no need for linenumbers in the schema
schema = yaml.load(schema_text)
v = cerberus.Validator()
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()

def my_construct_mapping(self, node, maptyp, deep=False):
    if not isinstance(node, ruamel.yaml.nodes.MappingNode):
        raise ruamel.yaml.constructor.ConstructorError(
            None, None, f'expected a mapping node, but found {node.id!s}', node.start_mark,
        )
    total_mapping = maptyp
    if getattr(node, 'merge', None) is not None:
        todo = [(node.merge, False), (node.value, False)]
    else:
        todo = [(node.value, True)]
    for values, check in todo:
        mapping = self.yaml_base_dict_type()
        for key_node, value_node in values:
            # keys can be list -> deep
            key = self.construct_object(key_node, deep=True)
            # lists are not hashable, but tuples are
            if not isinstance(key, Hashable):
                if isinstance(key, list):
                    key = tuple(key)
            if not isinstance(key, Hashable):
                raise ruamel.yaml.constructor.ConstructorError(
                    'while constructing a mapping',
                    node.start_mark,
                    'found unhashable key',
                    key_node.start_mark,
                )
            value = self.construct_object(value_node, deep=deep)
            if check:
                if self.check_mapping_key(node, key_node, mapping, key, value):
                    mapping[key] = value
            else:
                mapping[key] = value
            if not hasattr(self.loader, 'keyline'):
                self.loader.keyline = {}
            self.loader.keyline[key] = key_node.start_mark.line + 1  # ruamel.yaml start line-count at 0
        total_mapping.update(mapping)
    return total_mapping

yaml.Constructor.construct_mapping = my_construct_mapping


data = yaml.load(input_text)
v.validate(data, schema)
for key, val in v.errors.items():
    print(f'error for key "{key}" at line {yaml.keyline[key]}: {"".join(val)}')
```

which gives:

```
error for key "age" at line 2: min value is 10
```

Comment: It seems like the API for some of the internals has changed since you gave this answer, e.g., maptyp is no longer a parameter to construct_mapping and even when I remove that, at the point when I want to print out the errors, yaml.keyline doesn't exist. Is there an updated example with the current ruamel.yaml code?

Comment: To be clear, this is not using an API, these are internals that might change without notice. But the construct_mapping method (on ruamel.yaml.constructor.RoundTripConstructor still has the maptyp parameter) and that is what is assigned to the Constructor attribute of a YAML instance if you use `typ='rt'` or do not specify that parameter.